# IOS: Unzip file to directory (loaded from IAP)

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, zip, nsfilemanager

I want to unzip file  but did not get it. Debugging did not get me understand where is my mistake

My code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *pathDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directoryFilesName = @"Files";
NSString *directoryFilesPath = [[pathDocumentDirectory objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryFilesName];
NSString *zipPath = downloadedItem.contentURL.path;
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL isDir = YES;

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:zipPath])
{
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n");
    NSLog(@"pathDocumentDirectory = %@", pathDocumentDirectory);
    NSLog(@"directoryFilesPath = %@", directoryFilesPath);
    NSLog(@"zipPath = %@", zipPath);

    // Create PurchasedBooks directory
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryFilesPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryFilesPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.description);
        }
    }

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.description);
    }

    if ([SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:directoryFilesPath overwrite:YES password:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unziped and Moved");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Unziped and Moveed");
    }
 if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.description);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pathDocumentDirectory = (
    "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/453B1D9E-4ABD-46F6-8381-529FF9279130/Documents"
)

directoryFilesPath = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/453B1D9E-4ABD-46F6-8381-529FF9279130/Documents/Files

zipPath = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/453B1D9E-4ABD-46F6-8381-529FF9279130/Library/Caches/2E989856-A4BC-41CA-9109-18BC9FC1C3F8.zip

ERROR: Unziped and Moveed

ERROR: Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomain Code=-1 "failed to open zip file" UserInfo=0x17dda3b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=failed to open zip file}
```

Comment: Try using one of the other `unzipFileAtPath` methods that provides error info so you can determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: ERROR: Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomain Code=-1 "failed to open zip file" UserInfo=0x17dda3b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=failed to open zip file}

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the file `2E989856-A4BC-41CA-9109-18BC9FC1C3F8.zip` is really a valid zip file? Get the file onto your computer and see what it really is.

Comment: Does the error occur while trying to open it or save it?